# How to collect logs from java app (k8s) to fluentd(k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I have java app in k8s and fluentd (daemonset). In fluentd conf:

```
 *`<source>
     @type forward
     port 24224
  </source>
  <match **>
  @type stdout
  </match>`*
```

I am little bit confused. 
Do I need use fluentd-logger-java lib? I read in docs, that I need add remotehost for fluentd, but here i don't use service in general.
How app will send logs to fluentd pods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your Java application can log to `stdout` and `stderr` you’ll use fluentd to read that log and, in most cases, ship these logs to a system that can aggregate the logs.

This picture, from the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/), shows a common pattern of configuring node-level logging in Kubernetes with e.g. fluentd as Pods deployed with a DaemonSet:

[image]

In the above picture, the `logging-agent` will be fluentd and `my-pod` will be your Pod with a container running your Java app. The `Logging Backend`, from a fluentd configuration perspective, is optional but of course highly recommended. Basically you can choose to output your logs via fluentd `stdout`.

For this to function properly fluentd will need read access to the container logs, this is accomplished by mounting the log dir e.g. `/var/lib/docker/containers` into the fluentd container.

We’ve successfully used [this fluentd example ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-configmap.yaml), with some modifications to read logs from the nodes and ship them to Elasticsearch. Check out the `containers.input.conf` part of that ConfigMap for more info on container logs and how to digest them.

Note that you shouldn't need to use the `fluentd-logger-java` library to start using fluentd, although you could use it as another type of logger in your Java application. Out-of-the-box you should be able to let Java log everything to `stdout` and `stderr` and read the logs with fluentd.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just concerned with the live logs then you can try a product built on fluent,Elastic search and kibana ; you can get it https://logdna.com.

Just add a tag and deploy the demonset.

You can try its free trail for some days

Comment: Just add a tag and deploy the demonset.
 -- > How to add tag in Daemonset/Deployment file? samples pls

Comment: u can edit the demonset of logdna, that belongs to the respective environment , say "dev" tag is being used for development cluster in which you added a secret generated by logdna and this will start giving you logs at logdna dashboards against that tag